# Как в Tkinter сделать так, чтобы одновременно могло быть открыто лишь одно такое окно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

К примеру всплывающие окна. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии это окно не открывалось, если уже открыта его копия?

**Самый примитивный пример:**

```
from tkinter import *
head = Tk()

head.geometry('800x500')
head.title('Лаунчер')

def new_window():
    win = Tk()
    win.geometry('300x200')
    win.title('Ошибка')
    win_frame = Frame(new_window)
    win_frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    win.mainloop()

frame = Frame(head)
frame.place(relwidth = 1,relheight = 1)

button = Button(frame,text = 'Далее',command = new_window)
button.place(x = 350,y = 370,width = 130,height = 50)

head.mainloop()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick , отредачил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> К примеру всплывающие окна. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии это окно не открывалось, если уже открыта его копия?

1. Добавляете в ваш класс булевую переменную, например: `popup_init: bool = False`,
2. В методе, который открывает попап проверяете значение данной переменной, и не даёте открыть его повторно или деактивируете клавишу поп-апа если значение `is False`.
3. При нажатии на клавишу открытия поп-апа или при закрытии его меняете значение переменной.

Comment: Если несложно,прикрепите пожалуйста реальный пример,просто ниразу не использовал popup

Comment: Формируйте вопрос таким образом, чтобы было понятно что вы ждёте.

Comment: Отредачил вопрос

Comment: По прежнему мой ответ - совпадает с вашим вопросом)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, в коде можно использовать способ о котором сказал [Андрей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1263100),но как по мне, проще просто зафокусить окно с помощью:

```
root.grab_set()
```

Или же:

```
root.focus_get()
```